# Getting error: "Error 2 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'openNI.lib'" when trying to build NiViewer example of OpenNI

Tags: visual-studio, kinect, openni

I have successfully installed OpenNI and the associated drivers etc. I can successfully run the precompiled NiViewer program, but when i try to build the sample in VS2010 I get the error:

> Error 2   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'openNI.lib'    C:\Program Files\OpenNI\Samples\NiViewer\LINK   NiViewer

I can find only one mention of a file openNI.lib anywhere on the lib, and it was someone reporting the same error as me, and received no replies.

Any help MUCH appreciated

Comment: Quote: `Please don't forget to look at the README files for all the above projects since it contains important information on how to build & install the code.`

Comment: Struggling with the same error in vs2008 c++ express, haven't found anything useful so far
Nothing in main.cpp and this is the only error Followed instructions as laid out in OpenNI documentation, "$(OPEN_NI_INCLUDE)","$(OPEN_NI_LIB)", OpenNI.lib all added to corresponding places error - LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'OpenNI.lib'

Answer (score 1):

On "Computer", "Properties", "Advanced system settings", "Advanced" tab, then the button "Environment variables". Down there you can see the variables, check if the OPEN_NI_LIB is there and with the right path. Maybe it's missing those.

Comment: Forgot to mention, that's for Windows 7.